# Is the European Single Market a Free Trade Area?

Tags: international-trade

The European Single Market is (obviously) a Single Market.

Are Single Markets also free trade areas?

Answer (score 1):

Free trade area means there's no customs checking goods traded within that area.

From Wikipedia:

> The European Single Market, Internal Market or Common Market is a single market which seeks to guarantee the free movement of goods, capital, services, and labour – the "four freedoms" – within the European Union (EU).

So goods are traded freely within the EU, and hence EU is an FTA.

Comment: I don't think that's the most common meaning of "free trade area" and it is certainly used in slightly different ways.  According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free-trade_area) it's most often used to mean the area covered by an FTA, but FTAs often don't eliminate all tariffs and generally don't allow free movement of non-originating goods, so customs checks at borders remain necessary.  The EU abolished customs checks through later stages of economic integration.

Comment: Good point. I guess what I was thinking was a customs union. The point, though, is that, in my view, FTA is a necessary condition for a single market.